# Difference between an "IS" or "AS" function/procedure declaration PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure

When declaring a procedure/function in an ORACLE database, we can find this :

```
   CREATE FUNCTION get_bal(acc_no IN NUMBER) 
   RETURN NUMBER 
   IS acc_bal NUMBER(11,2);
   BEGIN 
   ...
```

In the example above, we use "IS" just before the variable declaration.
But I've also seen that we can use "AS".

What's the difference between "IS" and "AS"?
Thanks in advance.